# I copied a image from one dir to another but it opens up as a grey screen

Tags: java, android

The goal is, I think, quite simple: Copy one file to a folder within my application.
Please note that I am using the below style as I am targeting Android APIs 19+ and every time I try to use
the "Path" class, Android chucks a warning say it targets Api 22+ (If I remember correctly)

I copy a file, that the user picks, using the following:

```
InputStream usersFile = new FileInputStream(fromFile);

                 OutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(destFolder + "/" + fileName);
                 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = usersFile.read(buf)) > 0)
                    {
                        outFile.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
```

This I believe works fine, as when I take a look at the folder through my app, I can see the new file there.
So the next step is to use Android Intents to get it to open by asking the user to choose a program, based upon it's mime type:

```
String extensionFromFile = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fullFilePath);
        String fileMimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extensionFromFile);

        Log.i(TAG,extensionFromFile);
        Log.i(TAG, fileMimeType);
        Log.i(TAG, fullFilePath);

        Intent openTheFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        openTheFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        openTheFile.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fullFilePath),fileMimeType);
        startActivity(openTheFile);
```

The option will come up, I pick gallery but then it just takes me to a grey screen.
I take a look at details and just see a date with the year 1970?!

I am not sure why, how do I go about copy a file from a source to a dest?
I do want to use input stream and output stream because I hope to then add bytes to the file in the future.

The log.i does show the correct Mime type, if it is jpeg or jpg it will state it correctly.

Also, it may be helpful if I could access the files within my app through a file manager, but Android will only let root users or the app access the files (which is a good thing, but I do not know how to set it to let public users access the files. This is mainly for testing purposes though)

Comment: Are you sure that when you copy the file, you copy it with the same file extension?  And also that the file extension in fact matches its contents (meaning you don't have a file with JPEG contents named as a .png)?

Comment: @eattrig Yea I am sure, I did check that and if the original file is a jpg, then it will save it as a jpg.

Comment: What happens if you manually copy the file into the folder and bypass your copy algorithm?  Also, in the code above, did you close the output stream after you got done copying?

Comment: I agree with @eattrig. Check the size of the copies file. If it's 0 or smaller then the original file, you didn't close the output stream after copying and no/not all the data arrived in the destination file.

Comment: @eattrig Yea I did close it. Sorry I should have added that

Comment: You should have started with the code to select a file. If you do it in a normal way you would get an uri. Hence code like `new FileInputStream(fromFile);` would be impossible as you should have opened an InputStream for the obtained uri.

Comment: @blackapps did copy the file to an external folder and it copies fine.

Comment: @eattrig I did copy the file to an external folder and it copies fine.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: This was due to the folder permissions within the application.
You can't open the file from within the folder as normal users will not have permissions. You'll need to be root to have full access.

I overcame this by creating a folder in the external storage which is accessible by all.